# How can I send canvas information to be executed in another browser over nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a javascript programm, which uses canvas to draw:

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>digitale Tafel</title>
    <div id="spielfeld"></div>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="static/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/draw.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### javascript

```
var malen = {
    gemaltBis: 0,
    koordinaten: {},
    menu: {
        farben: [
            'white',
            'blue',
            'red',
            'black',
            'darkgreen',
            'yellow',
            'orange',
            'purple',
            'saddlebrown',
            'grey',
            'pink'
        ],
        breiten: [
            3,
            6,
            9,
            12,
            15
        ]
    },
    punkte: [],
    letztePunkte: [],
    serverPunkte: 0,
    vomServer: []
}

malen.durchmesser = 3;
malen.colorStatus = 'black';
$('<div>').addClass('leiste').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: -1+'px',
    left: 70+'px',
    width: 625+'px',
    height: 40+'px',
    border: 1+'px solid grey',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 20+'px',
    borderBottomRightRadius: 20+'px',
}).appendTo('#spielfeld');

for (color in malen.menu.farben) {
    $('<div>').addClass('farben').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 9+'px',
        left: 100+color*30+'px',
        width: 20+'px',
        height: 20+'px',
        backgroundColor: malen.menu.farben[color],
        borderRadius: 15+'px',
    }).click(farbeÄndern).appendTo('#spielfeld');

}

for (breite in malen.menu.breiten) {
    $('<div>').addClass('esels').css({
        border: 1+'px solid grey',
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 2+'px',
        left: 450+breite*45+'px',
        width: 40+'px',
        height: malen.menu.breiten[breite]+'px',
        backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
        borderRadius: 15+'px',
    }).click(dickeÄndern).appendTo('#spielfeld');
}

function farbeÄndern() {
    $('.farben').css({'border':0+'px'});
    malen.colorStatus = this.style.backgroundColor;
    document.getElementsByClassName('farben')[malen.menu.farben.indexOf(malen.colorStatus)].style.border = 2+'px solid';
    this.style.borderColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
    $('.esels').eq(malen.menu.breiten.indexOf(malen.durchmesser)).css({backgroundColor: malen.colorStatus,});
}

function dickeÄndern() {
    $('.esels').css({'background-color':'lightgrey'});
    malen.durchmesser = ((parseFloat(this.style.left)-450)/45+1)*3;
    this.style.backgroundColor = malen.colorStatus;
}

$('.farben').eq(malen.menu.farben.indexOf('black')).css({border: 2+'px solid',})
$('.esels').eq(malen.menu.breiten.indexOf(3)).css({backgroundColor: malen.colorStatus});
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
malen.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

$(window).resize(function () {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerWidth;
    for (sache in malen.menu.breiten) {
        $('.esels').eq(sache).css({height: malen.menu.breiten[sache]*canvas.width/500+'px'})
    }
    draw(0);
}).resize();

$('#canvas').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    captureMousePoint(e)
    $('#canvas').on('mousemove', captureMousePoint);
}).on('mouseup', function () {
    $('#canvas').off('mousemove', captureMousePoint);
})

function captureMousePoint(e){
    var einPunkt = {
        x: 1 / canvas.width * e.pageX,
        y: 1 / canvas.width * e.pageY,
        radius: malen.durchmesser/2,
        farbe: malen.colorStatus,
    };
    malen.punkte.push(einPunkt);
    malen.letztePunkte.push(einPunkt);
    draw(malen.punkte.length - 1);
}


function draw(since) {
    var len = malen.punkte.length;
    for (var i=since; i< len; i++) {
        malen.ctx.beginPath();
        malen.ctx.fillStyle = malen.punkte[i].farbe;
        malen.ctx.arc(
            malen.punkte[i].x * canvas.width,
            malen.punkte[i].y * canvas.width,
            malen.punkte[i].radius * canvas.width/500,
            0,
            2*Math.PI
        );
        malen.ctx.fill();
    }
}

function anServerSenden() {
    console.log("anServerSenden", malen.letztePunkte.length);
    if (malen.letztePunkte.length == 0) {
        window.setTimeout(anServerSenden, 1000);
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/data/test',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: JSON.stringify(malen.letztePunkte),
        success: function(fromServer){
            malen.vomServer = fromServer;
            console.log("Antwort vom Server", malen.vomServer);
            window.setTimeout(anServerSenden, 1000);
        }
    });
    malen.letztePunkte = [];
}

vomServerMalen();
function vomServerMalen() {
    for (item in malen.vomServer.punkte) {
        malen.ctx.beginPath();
        malen.ctx.fillStyle = malen.vomServer.punkte[item].farbe;
        malen.ctx.arc(
            malen.vomServer.punkte[item].x * canvas.width,
            malen.vomServer.punkte[item].y * canvas.width,
            malen.vomServer.punkte[item].radius * canvas.width/500,
            0,
            2*Math.PI
        );
        malen.ctx.fill();
    }
    window.setTimeout(vomServerMalen, 1000);
}


anServerSenden();
```

And I want it to be an application, which can be used in a server-client-application for multiple clients. Therefor I am using nodejs and try to send the stats of every point I draw, in an array, so that another client can get these informations for every point and draw exactly this on his browser.

### nodejs

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');

function dateiLesen(dateiName, naechsteFunktion) {
    fs.readFile(dateiName, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            naechsteFunktion("Kann nicht geladen werden: "+dateiName);
        } else {
            naechsteFunktion(data);
        }
    });
}

var listeGesamt = [];
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.url);
    console.log(request.method, request.url);
    console.log("  ", request.url.substring(1));
    var found;
    if (request.url === '/') {
        request.url = '/draw.html';
        // redirect auf eine BildId → über HTTP-Header im Response
    } else if (found = request.url.match(/^\/static\/([^\/]+)$/)) {
        console.log(found);
        dateiLesen(found[1], function(data){ response.end(data); })

    } else if (found = request.url.match(/^\/data\/(\w+)$/)) {
        var daten = '';
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.on('data', function (chunk) {
            daten += chunk;
        }).on('end', function (){
            // alle Daten geladen
            liste = JSON.parse(daten);
            listeGesamt = listeGesamt.concat(liste);
            console.log("alle Daten: ", liste)
            response.end(JSON.stringify({
                "Datensaetze empfangen": liste.length,
                serverListe: listeGesamt.length,
                punkte: liste
            }));
        })

    } else if (/^\/\w+$/.test(request.url)) {
        dateiLesen('draw.html', function(data){ response.end(data); })
    } else {
        response.end("Kann Anfrage nicht bearbeiten");
    }
}).listen(8081);
```

How can I make another browser to draw these points, that are send in the array 'liste'?

Comment: Maybe in some different words: "How can I draw at the same time on two open browsers. I draw on the one and the other uses the sended stats to draw it automaticaly?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my answer, it was really easy:

```
a²+b²=c²  |Math.sqrt()
a+b=c     |-b |-c
a-c=b
```

Comment: Nice guy, thank you for your help, you really helped me a lot! You are such a brain!